# how can I stop diff when one file has ended?

Tags: python, linux, diff

I'm comparing 2 files that are different by length but i don't want to see the output of the longer file after the shorter file has ended.
though i do need to know if there are missing lines on either file before the end of the shorter file.

I don't have to use diff, I might use python to do this, is there an easy way to do the same on python?

Comment: How about use `wc -l` to get the number of lines, and pass that to `head -n` to only output this many lines. then pipe that to `diff`.

Comment: that would only work if the differences appear before the n'th line, which is not always guaranteed

Comment: can you give a bit more detail on the context in which you need to solve this problem?

Comment: So, what do you want to compare? Line 1 vs line1 and line 2 vs line2, or some other?

Comment: @pocketfullofcheese
i have a system that generate a log of input data and i can replay that data to the system and get a new log.
I want to compare those two logs to see that the system works the same every time
the original logs can contain 19,000,000 lines!! so i dont want to replay all the log and i stop the replay after a while.

Answer (score 1):

See if this solution works for you :

```
dhruvpathak@dhruvpathak:~$ cat shortfile
this is a
short file
created
for example
dhruvpathak@dhruvpathak:~$ cat longfile
this is a
long file
created
for example.
but also contains
some extra text
which needs to be
ignored when
the small file 
ends.

dhruvpathak@dhruvpathak:~$ cat shortfile > /tmp/a && echo "*****ENDMARKER*****" >> /tmp/a && cat longfile > /tmp/b && diff /tmp/a /tmp/b | grep -B 100000 "*****ENDMARKER*****"
2c2
< short file
---
> long file
4,5c4,10
< for example
< *****ENDMARKER*****
```

Comment: thanx but this is useful for short files, my files can reach up to 20M    lines for the original file
so the execution of this will be too long